# How to change the width of a slider tick in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, width

How to change a width of ticks on a horizontal slider control in WPF.

I have found how to change the height of a tick but no width.

Comment: Really... do a _bit_ of research, please. [This](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-slider-control/) is the first result when googling "WPF slider control". From that page, tick width seems to work the other way around; you don't set a width, you set an amount of valid values between each tick, in `TickFrequency`.

Comment: really you thing i am that incompetent? :) i need to change the thickness(width) of the tick line not the TickFrequency. and i cant find nothing ..

Comment: Sorry, but that is completely unclear from your question...  it only mentions "width", not "line thickness".

Answer (score 1):

I've tried doing a custom tickbar for my own re-templated slider.
Matching the ticks up proved to be a nuisance but that's partly because of the rest of my template. I decided it wasn't worth the time necessary in the end.

The tickbar isn't done using xaml controls like you might expect. It's drawn onto the control and customising it is tricky stuff.

Your options include:

Re-Template the slider completely and build your own ui to your requirements.

Inherit from slider and override onrender as described here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d64b2dc-4dfd-4b05-aa95-e24aaaed53af/i-want-to-add-lables-with-text-in-ticks-of-slider?forum=wpf

Comment: Ok thank you.. if they inserted Height for tick why didnt they include Width, makes no sense.

Comment: You might have thought making the thing xaml would be kind of the obvious way to go. Don't know about you but I've worked on apps where I was short of time. Did something or other and meant to go back and change it. Then never did.